# Convert jpg with exif header into geotiff

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, jpg, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have bunch of jpgs with exif headers like this:

```
   Size is 4000, 3000
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  EXIF_ApertureValue=(3.625)
  EXIF_ColorSpace=1
  EXIF_ComponentsConfiguration=0x1 0x2 0x3 00
  EXIF_CompressedBitsPerPixel=(5)
  EXIF_CustomRendered=0
  EXIF_DateTime=2015:09:09 15:27:28
  EXIF_DateTimeDigitized=2015:09:09 15:27:28
  EXIF_DateTimeOriginal=2015:09:09 15:27:28
  EXIF_DigitalZoomRatio=(1)
  EXIF_ExifVersion=0230
  EXIF_ExposureBiasValue=(0)
  EXIF_ExposureMode=0
  EXIF_ExposureTime=(0.0005)
  EXIF_FileSource=0x3
  EXIF_Flash=16
  EXIF_FlashpixVersion=0100
  EXIF_FNumber=(3.5)
  EXIF_FocalLength=(4.5)
  EXIF_FocalPlaneResolutionUnit=2
  EXIF_FocalPlaneXResolution=(16393.4)
  EXIF_FocalPlaneYResolution=(16393.4)
  EXIF_GPSAltitude=(91.8)
  EXIF_GPSAltitudeRef=00
  EXIF_GPSDateStamp=2015:09:09
  EXIF_GPSLatitude=(45) (18) (3.564)
  EXIF_GPSLatitudeRef=N
  EXIF_GPSLongitude=(19) (48) (19.842)
  EXIF_GPSLongitudeRef=E
  EXIF_GPSMapDatum=WGS-84
  EXIF_GPSStatus=A
  EXIF_GPSTimeStamp=(14) (27) (29)
  EXIF_GPSVersionID=0x2 0x3 00 00
  EXIF_ImageDescription=                               
  EXIF_Interoperability_Index=R98
  EXIF_Interoperability_Version=0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30
  EXIF_ISOSpeedRatings=800
  EXIF_Make=Canon
  EXIF_MakerNote=
  EXIF_MaxApertureValue=(3.625)
  EXIF_MeteringMode=5
  EXIF_Model=Canon PowerShot SX280 HS
  EXIF_Orientation=1
  EXIF_PixelXDimension=4000
  EXIF_PixelYDimension=3000
  EXIF_Related_Image_Length=3000
  EXIF_Related_Image_Width=4000
  EXIF_ResolutionUnit=2
  EXIF_SceneCaptureType=0
  EXIF_SensingMethod=2
  EXIF_ShutterSpeedValue=(10.9688)
  EXIF_UserComment=
  EXIF_WhiteBalance=1
  EXIF_XResolution=(180)
  EXIF_YCbCrPositioning=2
  EXIF_YResolution=(180)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 3000.0)
Upper Right ( 4000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4000.0, 3000.0)
Center      ( 2000.0, 1500.0)
Band 1 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 2000x1500, 1000x750, 500x375
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 2 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 2000x1500, 1000x750, 500x375
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 3 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 2000x1500, 1000x750, 500x375
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

They were taken with UAV from about 100m height and i want to stich them into one image.
I want to convert them into GeoTiff so i can create image mosaic in geoserver.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more information on the source of these jpgs / how they were created? It looks like the EXIF coordinates are for one location only?

Comment: I edited my question now and added all exif properties inside.Picture was taken with Canon PowerShot SX280 HS from UAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longitude and latitude coordinates could be used to set up a local CRS in the center of the image (or one corner). I assume these are degree-minutes-seconds, which have to be converted to decimal degrees.

You have to find out how to use the resolution values, and how a rotation from North up is documented in the tags. You can georeference a sample image to known maps or imagery to get that right.

http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html can give you some hints on the used tags.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is how to stitch UAV jpgs together, here are some software options for mosaicing drone imagery

Open Drone Map (free, open source)
http://opendronemap.github.io/odm/

Palentier (free)
http://www.palentier.com/index.html

Pix4D (commercial, but there is a limited free version)
https://pix4d.com/buy_rent/

Agisoft Photoscan (commercial)
http://www.agisoft.com/

Drone Mapper (commercial SasS)
https://dronemapper.com/

I don't know specifically, but I suspect all of these have options for saving the resulting mosaic as a GeoTIFF

Comment: No, i just want to convert this jpg into Geotiff.I tried using gdal_translate but i couldnt get coordinates for resulting geotiff.